# Json.NET serialization of ObservableCollection "cannot be used on the current platform"

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, json.net, windows-8.1

I've come across a weird problem when trying to use Json.NET to deserialize json into my custom type:

```
public class Shot 
{
    [JsonProperty("frames")]
    public ObservableCollection<Frame> Frames
    {
        get { return Frames = _frames ?? new ObservableCollection<Frame>(); }
        set { _frames = value; }
    }
}
```

which is producing this exception:

> The API
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[AxisCtrl.Core.Model.Frame,
>   AxisCtrl.Core.Logic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AxisCtrl.Core.Model.Frame])'
>   cannot be used on the current platform. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.

when I try to deserialize json into this type from inside a Windows 8.1 windows store app, but is working when run inside a "Class Library" type project in my unit test environment:

The mentioned url is dead and is redirecting to the main page, so not much help there.
The weird thing is that this was working before I started splitting my projects and classes into a different structure. However I did not move the Shot class or change type of project it is contained in.

The Shot class is defined inside a Portable Class Library type project for ".NET Framework 4.5 and higher", "Windows Store apps (Windows 8) and higher" and "Windows Phone 8" and the main project is a Windows 8.1 application.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that ctor used by Json.NET for ObservableCollection is not avaiable in WinRT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can bypass this by overriding contract resolver

```
ContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
     public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
     {
        //check if type is ObservableCollection
        if (type.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType
                 && type.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
                          == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
        {
            //use list as default contract
            var c = (JsonArrayContract) 
                      base.ResolveContract(typeof(List<>)
                          .MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments[0]));
            //use Activator to create instance
            c.DefaultCreator = () => Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return c;
         }
         else return base.ResolveContract(type);
     }
}
```

And then set instance of your contract resolver in `JsonSettings` or `JsonSerializer` property called `ContractResolver`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I add that class the PCL compiles fine, but my main project produces this error: "Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed.". When I remove the class, the project compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @atsjoo, do you have Json.Net referenced from your main (executable) project?